Why does blender save animations even when i want them to be deleted?
I don't know what more do i have to do to delete those animations... deleted the frames, toggled the shield thing, deleted their name... closed and opened again the blender file and they are still here.
not only are they a pain in the ass but they also slow down exporting to gltf


Right next to the selected "Action" you see the number 2. This means there are two so-called "users" that use this action. One user is right here -the selection box- and there is another object that uses it. This is the reason why the action is not discarded when you save the file. So, either find the other user and remove the action from it or go to the outliner, switch it to "Blender File" (the 2nd symbol in the header is a drop-down menu, to the left of the search field), expand "Actions" and delete the action.

@Blunder i don't even know what an user is in blender
